# Ionic list - gridding with buttons

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, grid

Trying to achieve a list that has a label and two buttons in each item of the list. Having trouble with the styling. Attached code and a picture of what I would like to achieve.

```
<ion-content>
 <ion-list>
  <ion-item>
   <ion-label> Do you have any symptoms?></ion-label>
    <ion-row>
     <ion-col size="4">
      <ion-button>Yes</ion-button>
       </ion-col>
     <ion-col size="4">
      <ion-button>No</ion-button>
       </ion-col>
     </ion-row>
    </ion-item>
```

[image: desired outcome]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an *ion-grid* inside your *ion-item* to make the *ion-item* have two rows. You also need to put the *ion-label* inside an *ion-row*.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-grid class="ion-no-margin ion-no-padding">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-label> Have you been in contact? </ion-label><br/>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button expand="block" fill="solid" color="dark">Yes</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button expand="block" fill="solid" color="light">No</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```